# PHP Search Through Files for Keyword (case insensitive)?

Tags: php, regex

So I have the following function:

```
function findMatches($pathToDirectory, $keyword){
    $results = array();
    $htmlString = "";
    $fileList = glob($pathToDirectory);
    natsort($fileList);

    foreach ($fileList as $search) {
        $contents = file_get_contents($search);
        $episodeTitle = fgets(fopen($search, 'r'));
        $episodeTitle = "<p class='episode_title'>$episodeTitle</p>";
        $sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $contents);
        foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
            if (strpos($sentence, $keyword)) {
                if (!in_array($episodeTitle, $results)) {
                    array_push($results, $episodeTitle);
                }
                array_push($results, $sentence);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($results as $result){
        $highlightedKeyword = '<span class="keyword_highlight">' . $keyword . '</span>';
        $newResult = str_replace($keyword, $highlightedKeyword, $result);

        $htmlString .= '<p class="search_result">' . $newResult . '</p>';
    }
    $totalResults = 'Total Results: <span class=\'number_result\'>' . count($results) . '</span>';
    return $htmlString = $totalResults . $htmlString;
}
```

It opens every text file in a directory (`$filelist`), takes its contents, splits them up into sentences (`$sentences`), and then saves the sentences that contain a user defined keyword into an array (`$results`).  Then, it iterates through `$results` to wrap the keyword in HTML (so that the word appears highlighted within the sentence to the user), and and finally it wraps each sentence in HTML and sends them for presentation to the user.

However, currently the function is case sensitive.  What's a good way to make it case insensitive?  I tried using `stripos()` instead of `strpos()` in the `foreach ($sentences as $sentence)` loop, and that made the search itself case insensitive (like I want), but the problem is I couldn't figure out how to highlight both upper and lowercase versions of the word correctly if I wrote the function this way.

Also please let me know if you need clarification on any of this, I'm not sure I explained it too well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stripos()` and also `str_ireplace()` when you're doing your highlighting.

Comment: So when I do that it actually changes the sentences themselves so that every time the keyword appears, it's uppercase if you entered uppercase and vice versa.  For example, if I search "Apples" it works for highlighting all instances of "Apples," but then it actually changes all instances of the lowercase form, "apples," to uppercase as well

Comment: then instead of `str_replace()` use `stripos()` to get the position and insert the tags before that position and since you know the length of the keyword insert the closing tag after the keyword.